# Explain output for Java 8 OCA preparation

Tags: java

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

class _{
    public static void main(String[] __A_V_)
    {
        String $="";
        for(int x=0;++x<__A_V_.length;)
        $ += __A_V_[x];     
        out.println($);
    }
}
```

And the command line:

> javac _.java
>
> java _ - A .

Plz Explain how O/p is "A." (Without space)

I am expecting "- A ." (With space)

Comment: i am preparing for OCA exam and i came across this code so just wanted the explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java _ - A .
```

is passing three arguments to the `main` method of your `_` class: "-", "A" and ".". The spaces are separators between arguments.

Your loop skips the first argument ("-") due to the pre-increment operator in `++x<__A_V_.length`.

Hence only the second and third arguments - `__A_V_[1]` (whose value is "A") and `__A_V_[2]` (whose value is ".") - are appended to the `$` String and printed.

If you changed it to

```
java _ "- A ."
```

you would be passing a single argument having the value "- A ." (this time the spaces will be part of the single argument) to the `main`. Now, however, skipping the first argument would mean that your `$` String would remain empty.

Comment: `- A .` is the input. It's still mostly the pre-increment still causing the not desired behaviour..

Comment: that is not the case as you explained, i know its pre-incremented so x ll start from 1 not 0

Comment: o/p is "A." (A and dot) , where i am expecting o/p is "- A ."(- followed by space then A followed by space and then dot)

Comment: @RuchirChauhan Its without space because space are denoting a separator on command line for your args.

Comment: @RuchirChauhan Your array looks like this: `{ [0] = "-", [1] = "A", [2] = "." }`. `++x` preincrements `x` to 1 before you start appending to `$`, so "-" is not part of output.

Comment: @RuchirChauhan OK, I missed both the second space and the '.'. now it is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Technically, two things:

- the spaces passed on the command line act as separators, they don't "show up" in the incoming args array
- the order of arguments matches the command line, but the loop iterating them is slightly out of the expected.

But beyond that, a distinct non-answer: as the real answer here is that the OP **debugs** such things himself. Seriously: when preparing for an *exam*, then the key skill the ability to find explanations yourself.

In this case here, the solution would be to either quickly turn to a debugger, or simply to enhance the given code to use some `println()` calls, for example to print out the actual values of the `x` index (and the contents of the incoming arguments array). In other words: this assignment can easily be solved by *observing* what the code does at runtime, therefore the OP should enable himself to *observe* what his code is doing.

Regarding the second question (from comments) why the loop works without an incr/decr ... let's quote the official tutorial:

> The three expressions of the for loop are optional; an infinite loop can be created as follows:

```
// infinite loop
for ( ; ; ) {
```

Identifying the corresponding section in the Java Language Spec is left as exercise to the user.

Comment: *"Seriously: when preparing for an exam, then the key skill the ability to find explanations yourself."* - Something that is lost on a lot of students.